# send build status from jenkins downstream job

Tags: jenkins, gitlab, git-merge

I have a job A which is triggered from GitLab webhook on a merge request event.
As post build step A sends the build status to GitLab and triggers B giving it the information which MR to build.
so far so good.

Now I would like to get also the build status from job B in GitLab to see if all build steps have passed before merging.

Any ideas how to deal with that?